# How can I push a value to a specific array index using mongoose in nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push values to an array at a specific index of an array using the following code:

```
Freezer.update(conditions, {$push: {shelves[shelfindex] : {"rackname": rackname, "columns": columns, "rows": rows, "spaces" : []}}}, function (err, doc){

          console.log(doc);
        })
```

where shelfindex is the index of the shelf at hand, that I find with a preceeding for loop (code not shown).

It's not working (the program won't even start up). I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

My shelves array is set up like:

```
[{"racks":[],"shelfname":"Shelf 1"},{"racks":[],"shelfname":"Shelf 2"},{"racks":[],"shelfname":"Shelf 3"}]
```

So for instance if I was trying to push rack data to "Shelf 1" I am attempting to push it to:

```
shelves[0].racks
```

Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Would have been a little bit helpful if you had shown your Freezer model schema. Nonetheless the following example is based on the sample data (example):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565236570f7f257d5feffa10"),
    "shelves" : [ 
        {
            "racks" : [],
            "shelfname" : "Shelf 1"
        }, 
        {
            "racks" : [],
            "shelfname" : "Shelf 2"
        }, 
        {
            "racks" : [],
            "shelfname" : "Shelf 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, pushing rack data to `"Shelf 1"` shelf in mongo shell would use the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator which only supports one level deep and only the first matching element in its update. Note, the `shelves` array field must appear as part of the query document, hence `{ "shelves.shelfname": "Shelf 1" }`:

```
db.freezer.update(
    { "shelves.shelfname": "Shelf 1" },
    {
        "$push": {
            "shelves.$.racks": {
                "rackname": 1, 
                "columns": 3, 
                "rows": 2, 
                "spaces" : []       
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Now, if you knew the specific array index then create the update document using the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**:

```
var update = { "$push": {} },
    condition = { };

condition["shelves.shelfname"] = "Shelf "+ shelfindex + 1;
update["$push"]["shelves."+ shelfindex +".racks" ] = {
    "rackname": rackname, 
    "columns": columns, 
    "rows": rows, 
    "spaces" : []
};

db.freezer.update(condition, update);
```

In your node.js, this would be similar but with a callback:

```
Freezer.update(conditions, update, function (err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
});
```